# rust futures::select modifying local variable in loop

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I have a struct G like this

```
struct G { /* some member */ }
impl G {
  async fn ref_foo(&self) { /* some code uses G's member */ }
  async fn mut_foo(&mut self) { /* some code modifies G's member */ }
}
```

which is responsible to handle requests from a `mpsc::Receiver`, like this -- which won't compile:

```
async fn run_loop(mut rx: impl Stream<Item = Task> + FusedStream + Unpin) {
  let mut g = G {};
  let mut QS = FuturesUnordered::new();
  loop {
    select! {
      t = rx.select_next_some() => match t {
        TR {..} => QS.push(g.ref_foo()),
        TM {..} => QS.push(g.mut_foo()),
      },
      _ = QS.select_next_some() => {},
    }
  }
}
```

the above code won't compile due to multiple mutable reference to `g`.

**Target:**

What I want is that the loop runs in parallel for any number of `ref_foo` tasks, and when it needs to run a `mut_foo` task, it waits until every `ref_foo` task finish, and then run the `mut_foo` task, then it can run other tasks as usual.

```
                / g.ref_foo() \                                    / ...
                | g.ref_foo() |                                    | ...
g.mut_foo() => <  g.ref_foo()  > => g.mut_foo() => g.mut_foo() => <  ...
                | g.ref_foo() |                                    | ...
                \ g.ref_foo() /                                    \ ...
```

**Additional Infomation:**

I used to move implementation of `mut_foo` to the select loop, and remove `async` on `g.mut_foo()` so that no mutable reference would be used in stream QS.

But this implementation is really cubersome and undoubtedly broke G's design.

---

Just now, I come up with another implementation by make a wrapper:

```
async fn run_task(mut g: G, t: Task) -> G {
  match t {
    TR {..} => g.ref_foo().await,
    TM {..} => g.mut_foo().await,
  };
  g
}
```

while in the select loop:

```
async fn run_loop(mut rx: impl Stream<Item = Task> + FusedStream + Unpin) {
  let g0 = G {};
  let mut QS = FuturesUnordered::new();
  let mut getter = FuturesUnordered::new();
  getter.push(ready(g0));
  loop {
    select! {
      t = rx.select_next_some() => {
        let mut g = getter.select_next_some().await;
        QS.push(run_task(g, t));
      },
      mut g = QS.select_next_some() => getter.push(ready(g)),
    }
  }
}
```

this one compiles, but it's not so "async" as it can possibly be. In this implementation, `ref_foo` tasks are also running sequentially.

**Question:**

1. Are there more material I should learn to solve this problem? The technics I'm using comes from [`rust-async-book`](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/06_multiple_futures/03_select.html)
2. Do I HAVE TO use `RefCell` to solve this problem? IMHO, this should be a trivial problem that can be solved without breaking rust's borrowing rules (by using `RefCell`).
3. Can I change my wrap `run_task` and the select loop so that `ref_foo` runs in parallel? I have problem in the implementation because G is flowing `getter => QS => getter => ...`, there's no long-term G instance, and I cannot figure out where I can store it.

**Append some of my thoughts:**

Since `mut_foo` can not be run in parallel, I am trying to solve this problem by removing `async` keyword on `mut_foo` -- with little progress. The core problem is that, immutable ref to G is needed for parallel running of `ref_foo`, but I have to get rid of all these immutable ref G when it's time for `mut_foo`. The fact do not change whether `mut_foo` is async or not ( or "whether `mut_foo` returns ref G or not").

Comment: I think there's some important part of the code that got lost in simplification: both `ref_foo` and `mut_foo` return some value. I suspect those values are references, tied to the lifetime of `&self` and `&mut self`, respectively, am I right?

Comment: @Thomas No. Or probably yes. The references comes from async keyword.

Comment: Ah, of course, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved Question 3 with a lot of `if` statements. I hope there are some more elegant implementations. And, I really appreciate any learning material as stated in Question 1.

here's the full code that compiles (simplified):

```rust
use tokio::runtime;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use futures::{
    select, StreamExt, SinkExt,
    future::{ready},
    stream::{FusedStream, FuturesUnordered, Stream},
};

struct G;

impl G {
    async fn ref_foo(&self) { println!("ref_foo +++"); tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(500)).await; println!("ref_foo ---"); }
    async fn mut_foo(&mut self) { println!("mut_foo +++"); tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(500)).await; println!("mut_foo ---"); }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
enum Task {
    TR,
    TM,
}

// wrappers
async fn run_ref_task(g: &G, task: Task) {
    match task {
        Task::TR => g.ref_foo().await,
        _ => {},
    };
}

async fn run_mut_task(mut g: G, task: Task) -> G {
    match task {
        Task::TM => g.mut_foo().await,
        _ => {},
    };
    g
}

async fn run_loop(mut rx: impl Stream<Item = Task> + FusedStream + Unpin) {
    let g0 = G;

    let mut getter = FuturesUnordered::new();
    getter.push(ready(g0));
    // the following streams stores only `ready(task)`
    let mut mut_tasks = FuturesUnordered::new(); // for tasks that's scheduled in this loop
    let mut ref_tasks = FuturesUnordered::new();
    let mut mut_delay = FuturesUnordered::new(); // for tasks that's scheduled in next loop
    let mut ref_delay = FuturesUnordered::new();

    loop {
        println!("============ avoid idle loops ============");
        let g = getter.select_next_some().await;
        {
            let mut queries = FuturesUnordered::new(); // where we schedule ref_foo tasks
            loop {
                println!("------------ avoid idle ref_task loops ------------");
                select! {
                    task = rx.select_next_some() => {
                        match &task {
                            Task::TR => ref_delay.push(ready(task)),
                            Task::TM => mut_tasks.push(ready(task)),
                        };
                        if mut_delay.is_empty() && ref_tasks.is_empty() && queries.is_empty() { break; }
                    },
                    task = mut_delay.select_next_some() => {
                        mut_tasks.push(ready(task));
                        if mut_delay.is_empty() && ref_tasks.is_empty() && queries.is_empty() { break; }
                    }
                    task = ref_tasks.select_next_some() => {
                        queries.push(run_ref_task(&g, task));
                    }
                    _ = queries.select_next_some() => {
                        if mut_delay.is_empty() && ref_tasks.is_empty() && queries.is_empty() { break; }
                    },
                }
            }
        }
        getter.push(ready(g));

        {
            let mut queries = FuturesUnordered::new(); // where we schedule mut_foo tasks
            loop {
                println!("------------ avoid idle mut_task loops ------------");
                select! {
                    task = rx.select_next_some() => {
                        match &task {
                            Task::TR => ref_tasks.push(ready(task)),
                            Task::TM => mut_delay.push(ready(task)),
                        };
                        if ref_delay.is_empty() && mut_tasks.is_empty() && queries.is_empty() { break; }
                    },
                    task = ref_delay.select_next_some() => {
                        ref_tasks.push(ready(task));
                        if ref_delay.is_empty() && mut_tasks.is_empty() && queries.is_empty() { break; }
                    }
                    g = getter.select_next_some() => {
                        if let Some(task) = mut_tasks.next().await {
                            queries.push(run_mut_task(g, task));
                        } else {
                            getter.push(ready(g));
                            if ref_delay.is_empty() && queries.is_empty() { break; }
                        }
                    }
                    g = queries.select_next_some() => {
                        getter.push(ready(g));
                        if ref_delay.is_empty() && mut_tasks.is_empty() && queries.is_empty() { break; }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let (mut tx, rx) = futures::channel::mpsc::channel(10000);
    let th = thread::spawn(move || thread_main(rx));
    let tasks = vec![Task::TR, Task::TR, Task::TM, Task::TM, Task::TR, Task::TR, Task::TR, Task::TM, Task::TM];

    let rt = runtime::Builder::new_multi_thread().enable_time().build().unwrap();
    rt.block_on(async {
        loop {
            for task in tasks.clone() {
                tx.send(task).await.expect("");
            }
            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(10)).await;
        }
    });
    th.join().expect("");
}

fn thread_main(rx: futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver<Task>) {
    let rt = runtime::Builder::new_multi_thread().enable_time().build().unwrap();
    rt.block_on(async {
        run_loop(rx).await;
    });
}
```